# with nested loops, creating several one-page aggregates of ggplots

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

This follows a previous question was answered so helpfully by @Duck. ([R ggpot: Arranging on one page several ggplots created with a loop / name each plot differenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65278770/r-ggpot-arranging-on-one-page-several-ggplots-created-with-a-loop-name-each-p/65278864#65278864P)). I was looking to put several ggplots created by a loop on one page. I made a model loop and @Duck provided a way to do just that. It worked so nicely, that I got an even bigger appetite and now want to nest the whole thing in another loop, creating several such pages (each present data from a different year).  But it’s not working well.

Here is what @Duck suggested, for several plots on one page:

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(patchwork)
  #Create list
  List <- list()
  cylinder<-unique(mtcars$cyl)
  #Loop
  for (value in seq_along(cylinder)) {
    m<-mtcars%>%
      filter(cyl==cylinder[value])%>%
      group_by (gear)%>%
      summarise(number=n(), average=mean(mpg), se=sd(mpg))
    print(m) # reporting the numbers
    
    a<-m%>%
      mutate(gear=factor(gear, levels=unique(gear)))%>%
      ggplot()+
      geom_bar(aes(x=gear, y=average), stat = 'identity', fill ='red') +
      geom_errorbar( aes(x= gear, ymin=average-se, ymax=average+se), width=0.2, colour="black", alpha=1, size=1) +
      xlab("gears") + ylab("average mpg") +
      ggtitle (paste( "cyliner:", value ))+
      theme(axis.ticks.x=element_blank())  
    print(a)
    List[[value]]<-a}
  #Wrap plots
  wrap_plots(List,nrow = 1)
```

Nice! Now, for the sake of simplicity, say we just want three of the same. Here is how I tried to nest it.

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(patchwork)
repeats<-c(1,2,3)  # for the outer loop. 
  List <- list()
  cylinder<-unique(mtcars$cyl)

    #Loop 1:
  
  for (pic in seq_along(repeats)) {
    
    # loop 2:
  
  for (value in seq_along(cylinder)) 
# same code:
    m<-mtcars%>%
      filter(cyl==cylinder[value])%>%
      group_by (gear)%>%
      summarise(number=n(), average=mean(mpg), se=sd(mpg))
    print(m) # reporting the numbers
    
    a<-m%>%
      mutate(gear=factor(gear, levels=unique(gear)))%>%
      ggplot()+
      geom_bar(aes(x=gear, y=average), stat = 'identity', fill ='red') +
      geom_errorbar( aes(x= gear, ymin=average-se, ymax=average+se), width=0.2, colour="black", alpha=1, size=1) +
      xlab("gears") + ylab("average mpg") +
      ggtitle (paste( "cyliner:", value ))+
      theme(axis.ticks.x=element_blank())  
    print(a)
    List[[value]]<-a}
  #Wrap plots
  wrap_plots(List,nrow = 1)

    List[[value]]<-a }
  #Wrap plots
  wrap_plots(List,nrow = 1)

      print (List) #reporter
  List <- list()
  print(List) #reporter
  
  }
```

Judge by how many times the lists is filled, then zeroed, the compilation goes through the loops correctly. But only 6 single plots are made (not 9), and no page with three wrapped plots. Suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved like so:

1. When using loops I prefer to put the plotting code in a separate function. Makes it easier to check, to debug and results (in my opinion) in cleaner and clearer code. Therefore I put the plotting code in a function `make_plot`.
2. I did the same for your inner loop. I created a function

   ```
   inner_loop <- function(x) {
     # Create list
     List <- lapply(seq_along(cylinder), make_plot)
     # Wrap plots
     wrap_plots(List, nrow = 1)  
   }
   ```

which loops over the `cylinder`s, makes a plot for each value and glues the plots together.

3. After these inital steps we can easily loop over `repeats`, call function `inner_loop` and finally glue the resulting list of pages together:

```
repeats <- c(1,2,3)  # for the outer loop. 
pages <- lapply(repeats, inner_loop)
wrap_plots(pages, ncol = 1)
```

Full reproducible code:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

cylinder <- unique(mtcars$cyl)

make_plot <- function(value) {
  m <- mtcars %>%
    filter(cyl == cylinder[value]) %>%
    group_by(gear) %>%
    summarise(number = n(), average = mean(mpg), se = sd(mpg))
  #print(m) # reporting the numbers
  
  m %>%
    mutate(gear = factor(gear, levels = unique(gear))) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(x = gear, y = average), stat = "identity", fill = "red") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(x = gear, ymin = average - se, ymax = average + se), width = 0.2, colour = "black", alpha = 1, size = 1) +
    xlab("gears") +
    ylab("average mpg") +
    ggtitle(paste("cylinder:", value)) +
    theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
}

inner_loop <- function(x) {
  # Create list
  List <- lapply(seq_along(cylinder), make_plot)
  # Wrap plots
  wrap_plots(List, nrow = 1)  
}

# Outer loop
repeats <- c(1,2,3)  # for the outer loop. 
pages <- lapply(repeats, inner_loop)

wrap_plots(pages, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

**EDIT** I adapted the example and the code a bit. Now the outer loop loops over the `gear`s. The value of `gear` is passed as an parameter to the inner loop and to the plot function, where it can be used to filter the dataset accordingly. As a result you nine different plots. One row per gear and the columns for the cylinders.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

make_plot <- function(value, .gear) {
  m <- mtcars %>%
    filter(cyl == cylinder[value], gear %in% .gear) %>%
    group_by(gear) %>%
    summarise(number = n(), average = mean(mpg), se = sd(mpg))
  
  m %>%
    mutate(gear = factor(gear, levels = unique(gear))) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(x = gear, y = average), stat = "identity", fill = "red") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(x = gear, ymin = average - se, ymax = average + se), width = 0.2, colour = "black", alpha = 1, size = 1) +
    xlab("gears") +
    ylab("average mpg") +
    ggtitle(paste("cylinder:", value)) +
    theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
}

inner_loop <- function(gear) {
  # Create list
  List <- lapply(seq_along(cylinder), make_plot, .gear = gear)
  # Wrap plots
  wrap_plots(List, nrow = 1)  
}

# Outer loop
cylinder <- unique(mtcars$cyl)
gears <- unique(mtcars$gear)
 # for the outer loop. 
pages <- lapply(gears, inner_loop)

wrap_plots(pages, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. But now I’m afraid  my example was _too_ simple. Rather than having identical repeats, I was trying to have each repeat do the same age analysis for a different year. Maybe a better example would have been,  repeat the cylinder effect for each gear.  That’s why my intuition goes: for year in years, for age_group in age…

Comment: Hi Gal. I already guessed that your example is too simplified. I just made an edit. This hopefully shows you the general approach to adapt the code to your needs. Best S.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan! What I had in mind though is one plot per gear. But I did build on your idea of using a function! Instead of nested loops, that is. A different approach, same end result – repeating the graph for different gears without re-writing a lengthy code. I put the code as a self-answer. Thanks for opening my (inexperienced) mind to the use of functions!

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote, the original task I am looking to do is repeating the same manipulation for each year in my database; my example, therefore, might be too simplistic. A better one would be to look at the effect of cylinder # on mpg for each gear #. While not the direction I thought this calls for (loop inside loop), I can avoid repeating the code for each gear by putting Duck’s code inside as a function, as suggested by Stefan.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

vls<-unique(mtcars$gear) #these are the values for the different plots.

mltplot<-function(geer) {
  
 # the original code, with additional filtering for a specific gear:
    
  #Create list
  List <- list()
  cylinder<-unique(mtcars$cyl)
  #Loop
  for (value in seq_along(cylinder)) {
    m<-mtcars%>%
      filter(gear==geer)%>% # filtering, we look at one gear at a time.
      filter(cyl==cylinder[value])%>%
      group_by (gear)%>%
      summarise(number=n(), average=mean(mpg), se=sd(mpg))
    print(m) # reporting the numbers
    
    a<-m%>%
      mutate(gear=factor(gear, levels=unique(gear)))%>%
      ggplot()+
      geom_bar(aes(x=gear, y=average), stat = 'identity', fill ='red') +
      geom_errorbar( aes(x= gear, ymin=average-se, ymax=average+se), width=0.2, colour="black", alpha=1, size=1) +
      xlab("gears") + ylab("average mpg") +
      ggtitle (paste( "cyliner:", value ))+
      theme(axis.ticks.x=element_blank())  
    
    List[[value]]<-a}
  #Wrap plots
  wrap_plots(List,nrow = 1)
  
}
```

Now I can ask for:

```
mltplot (vls[1])
mlrplor{vls[2])
mltplot{val[3[)
```